# Function to automatically Link predefined words in joomla using php preg_replace

Tags: php, function, hyperlink, preg-replace, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla/k2 component and I would like to automatically link certain keywords in articles. I did some research and came accross this function on http://coderzone.org/library/PHP-Auto-link-text-with-a-given-set-of_1085.htm

```
<?php 
// list of keywords to auto-link 
// list plural forms first
$reserved_word_list = array (

'dogs' => 'http://dogs.com', 
'dog' => 'http://dogs.com', 
'cat' => 'http://cats.com', 
'kitten' => 'http://cats.com',
'horse' => 'http://horses.com'
 }


// search text string and auto-link the words
foreach($reserved_word_list as $word => $rep_string){

if(strpos($some_text, $word)){

    // link the word
    $some_text = preg_replace('/(\s+)('.preg_quote($word).')/i','$1<a       href="'.$rep_string.'">$2</a>',$some_text);

    }
}    
?>
```

I pasted this function in my k2 template overide in joomla,just  above $this->item->maintext in item.php  and ended up with a blank page.

I am sure I have done something wrong but i cannot find out what it it!  Please take  a look at my code and see, thanks.

Comment: `);` not `}` to end the array for one.

Comment: Thanks, let me modify that.

Comment: Now the blank page is gone, but no links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in the code you've pasted, which is probably why it's not doing anything. Try this:

```
// set the text here; I've put in some sample text.
$some_text =  "<p>My favourite animals are cats and dogs, but I can't stand horses -- they suck!</p>";

// list of keywords to auto-link
// list plural forms first
$reserved_word_list = array (
    'dogs' => 'http://dogs.com',
    'dog' => 'http://dogs.com',
    'cat' => 'http://cats.com',
    'kitten' => 'http://cats.com',
    'horse' => 'http://horses.com',
    'horses' => 'http://alltheprettyhorses.com'
);

// search text string and auto-link the words
foreach($reserved_word_list as $word => $rep_string){
    if(strpos($some_text, $word)){
    // link the word
        $some_text = preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($word).')\b/i','<a href="'.$rep_string.'">$1</a>',$some_text);
    }
}
echo $some_text;
// returns <p>My favourite animals are cats and <a href="http://dogs.com">dogs</a>,
// but I can't stand <a href="http://alltheprettyhorses.com">horses</a> -- they suck!</p>
```

You'll need to alter the code so that `$some_text` is set to the page contents.

Comment: Thanks so much let me test that :), but I would like to replace '$some_text' with the actual k2 content: '$this->item->maintext' (this echos the articles main text)

Comment: Just do `$some_text = $this->item->maintext;`, and then at the end of the script, do `$this->item->maintext = $some_text;`

Comment: I am so happy:) it worked out great, but I realised that am going to have a lot of keywords and I am wondering if its possible to load keywords into the script from an external file. ex. keywords.php

Comment: Yes, of course -- you could have a 'dictionary' file in a set format (e.g. keyword[tab]url), and your script could open the file and parse it to create $reserved_word_list. You would only need to alter the dictionary file in the future, not the script itself.

Comment: Hmm interesting, how can i do that? Shall I ask another qusstion?

Comment: Yes, ask another Q (if you haven't already) since it's a separate topic, although first have a look at the docs for opening/reading files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php. It should be fairly easy to figure out.